# PHP Laravel Unit Testing, Custom Assert failure messages

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am new to Laravel and also unit testing in general.

I have written a simple test using the [guide from Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#response-assertions),

```
public function testGet(){
    $this->get('/api/accounts/1')->assertStatus(200)->assertJsonStructure([
        'status','data'
    ]);
}
```

When the test is run, it generates the following failure (which is intended):

```
Time: 127 ms, Memory: 12.00MB
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Unit\AccountApiTest::testGet
Invalid JSON was returned from the route.
```

My question is, is there any way we can customize the message generated when a test fails for all the available assertion in Laravel? For this case, the message

```
Invalid JSON was returned from the route.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot modify the message easily as it is hardcoded in the [Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8a74cf931b9df281707cef973ee9fba5b18793e8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php#L386):

```
/**
 * Validate and return the decoded response JSON.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $key
 * @return mixed
 */
public function decodeResponseJson($key = null)
{
    $decodedResponse = json_decode($this->getContent(), true);

    if (is_null($decodedResponse) || $decodedResponse === false) {
        if ($this->exception) {
            throw $this->exception;
        } else {
            PHPUnit::fail('Invalid JSON was returned from the route.');
        }
    }

    return data_get($decodedResponse, $key);
}
```

You may be able to get custom messages by overwriting the TestResponse.